# How to serve a single page AngularJS app from Laravel views/templates directory?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I am trying to combine a SPA angular app based off of [Mobile Angular UI](http://mobileangularui.com/demo/#/) that can take advantage of Laravel's features like csrf protection.  I can place the entire AngularJS app in Laravel's `public/` directory, but I'm not sure if that is the right way of doing it.

What I'm looking for is guidace on how to be able to serve an `index.php` that can interact with Laravel from which a single page AngularJS app would take over.  In my case, Laravel is an API for the single page app.

The problem:

1. Laravel route is defined for `/app3` which returns `index.php` from `templates/`

Of course, I'd prefer to define the route for `/app`, however, all AngularjS assets are located in `public/app/` and requesting `app/` returns a default directory listing since there is no index.php/html in `/app`.  Simply placing `index.php` in `public/` results in a blank page since for some reason, the PHP never gets parsed by the server.  Changing `index.php` to `index.html` works, but then how can I take advantage of things like Laravels csrf protection?

2. `index.php` loads all AngularJS resources correctly and without console errors.
3. Clicking on a sidebar link from `index.php`, which normally returns an AngularJS template which should be placed inside `index.php`, instead, loads the default directory listing shown when a directory contains no index.php/html.

Why do the AngularJS templates fail to load inside `index.php`?

What is the best way to combine a single page AngularJS app with Laravel?

Comment: Why can't you turn the HTML markup into a View and render it within the controller leveraged by the route? AngularJS is just HTML markup and JavaScript, you should be able to hook into your header variable and include the Angular JS, then put the Angular Markup into a view, and return the angular view from your controller when it hits the route that calls the controller, which in this case is `/app3`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, Please elaborate.  I'm not sure I understand.  Is a Laravel defined route necessary for every AngularJS templateUrl?  How could this be configured specifically?

Comment: Are you saying to include all the HTML & AngularJS code into a Laravel controller?  If I understand correctly, isn't that a bit ugly?

Comment: I've given an example below. For integrating your Angular Application I do not believe my method is ugly, but I have been mistaken many times before. :D

Comment: Here is example for new versions of Angular integrated in Laravel https://github.com/toni-rmc/laravel-angular-integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it. The problem was that my AngularJS route links were wrong.

Here are my working configurations:

---

```
Laravel
routes.php

...
$router->get('/app3', function() {
    return view('app3.index');
});
```

---

```
AngularJS
index.php

<base href="/" />

...

<!-- Sidebars -->
<div ng-include="'/app/sidebar.html'" 
        ui-track-as-search-param='true'
        class="sidebar sidebar-left"></div>
```

---

```
demo.js

  app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/',              {templateUrl: 'app/home.html', reloadOnSearch: false});
  $routeProvider.when('/app/',              {templateUrl: 'app/home.html', reloadOnSearch: false});
  $routeProvider.when('/app/scroll',        {templateUrl: 'app/scroll.html', reloadOnSearch: false}); 
  $routeProvider.when('/app/toggle',        {templateUrl: 'app/toggle.html', reloadOnSearch: false}); 
  $routeProvider.when('/app/tabs',          {templateUrl: 'app/tabs.html', reloadOnSearch: false}); 
  $routeProvider.when('/app/accordion',     {templateUrl: 'app/accordion.html', reloadOnSearch: false}); 
  $routeProvider.when('/app/overlay',       {templateUrl: 'app/overlay.html', reloadOnSearch: false}); 
  $routeProvider.when('/app/forms',         {templateUrl: 'app/forms.html', reloadOnSearch: false});
  $routeProvider.when('/app/dropdown',      {templateUrl: 'app/dropdown.html', reloadOnSearch: false});
  $routeProvider.when('/app/drag',          {templateUrl: 'app/drag.html', reloadOnSearch: false});
  $routeProvider.when('/app/carousel',      {templateUrl: 'app/carousel.html', reloadOnSearch: false});
  $routeProvider.when('/app/toggleLegacy',  {templateUrl: 'app/toggleLegacy.html', reloadOnSearch: false});
```

---

```
sidebar.html

  <a class="list-group-item" href="/app3/#/app">Home <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="/app3/#/app/scroll">Scroll <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="/app3/#/app/toggle">Toggle <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="/app3/#/app/tabs">Tabs <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="/app3/#/app/accordion">Accordion <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="/app3/#/app/overlay">Overlay <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="/app3/#/app/forms">Forms <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="/app3/#/app/dropdown">Dropdown <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="/app3/#/app/test/invoice">Invoice <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="/app3/#/app/test">Test <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a>
```

Hopefully this can help someone who wants to combine mobile-angular-ui with Laravel!

Thanks to @Ohgodwhy for clarifying that the AngularJS templates need to be in the `public/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

So let's say you have this route:

```
Route::get('/app3', 'RouteController@serveAngular');
```

Then you have a controller

```
class RouteController extends BaseController{
    public function serveAngular(){
        return View::make('angular/index');
    }
}
```

Then you've got

```
-views
    -angular
        -index.blade.php
```

Then in your index.blade.php you just include your angular markup

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
```

You are not required to put the `ng-app` definition at the top of the HTML markup, just the top of the application container.

Of course, you'd also have to include your AngularJS so your primary template would contain something like:

```
@yield('scripts')
</head>
```

That way you can easily hook into it within your angular template

```
@section('scripts')
<script src="/path/to/my/AnguularJS.js"></script>
@stop
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is kind of what I have already except without the controller.  Laravel's route definition links a closure right there and returns index.php (which could easily be index.blade.php), however, my problem with this method is that the AngularJS templates are not being included within `index.php`, but as a separate link.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `AngularJS templates are not being included within index.php, but as a separate link`. Can you pastebin something for me so I can see what we're talking about?

Comment: Please visit `http://persianturtle.com/app3/` and click on a link from the sidebar.  Perhaps this is the easiest way to explain what my problem is.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Shouldn't those links on the left autopopulate the data on the right instead of reloading the page?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, I have not been able to figure out how to configure the SPA so that it does autopopulate inside.  Do all the template files need to be located in the `public/` directory?  If so, what should the `<base href>` be set to?

Comment: Yep, All template files should be in your `/public` directory. Also, you should add `Option -indexes` to your `.htaccess` or `<Directory>` markup in your `httpd.conf` so people can't steal your goodies!

Comment: In case you are interested, I finally got it working and posted my configurations.  My problem was in AngularJS' routing definitions.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in the **public** folder

Content of each directories in the public folder:

```
public/app : Contains all AngularJS related JavaScript files (controllers and lib directories)
public/app/controllers: Contains all AngularJS controllers
public/app/lib : This directory will contain all AngularJS core files. You can also load AngularJS from a CDN network. 
public/css : Contains all CSS files.
public/js : Contains all regular JavaScript files for our UI.
```

You can have a read at a complete article at

http://deepdivetuts.com/create-laravel-and-angular-single-page-application-for-beginners-only